# How do I loop and update variables in Python

Tags: python, simulation

I am making an economic simulator. I'm trying to constantly loop and gain/lose money, but it doesn't show the updated values. It simply shows the default values and variables. I'm not very good with mathematical variables. I have looped it fairly successfully although I think it is resetting the variables each time it loops.

```py
import time

money = 2
moneyfo = "{:.2f}".format(money)

boughtw = 0
woodsalea = 1 
woodinv = 0
woodprice = (woodsalea * 2)
woodpricefo = "{:.2f}".format(woodprice)
amntw = 0
buywcost = 0

foodinv = 0
foodsalea = 1
foodprice = (woodsalea * 2)
foodpricefo = "{:.2f}".format(foodprice)
amntf = 0
buyfcost = 0

def start():
  print ("Products are wood food and stone")
  print ("""Prices are wood """ + woodpricefo + " food " + foodpricefo + " stone")

def buysale():
  bos = input("""Buy, Sell or Check Inventory?
""")
  if bos == ("Buy"):
    btyp = input("""Wood, Food, Or Stone?
""")
    if btyp == ("Wood"):
      amntw = input("""0-100
""")
      buywcost = float(amntw) * woodprice
  buywcostfo = "{:.2f}".format(buywcost)
  print ("That will be $" + buywcostfo + " you have " + str(money) + " dollars would you still like to buy?")
  buywyn = input("""Yes Or No
""")
  if buywyn == ("Yes") and money >= buywcost:
    print("You have bought Wood")
    boughtw = amntw
    boughtw = woodinv
    boughtw * woodprice - money
    woodsalea = boughtw
    print (woodsalea) 
    print (boughtw) 
    print (money)
    start()
    buysale()
  if bos == ("Sell"):
    styp = input("""Wood, Food, Or Stone
""")
    if styp == ("Wood"):
      amntw = input("""0-100
""")

start()
buysale()
```

Comment: Where are you looping? I just see `If` statements (though I guess they're "looping"?) -- also, can you fix the indentation please (you have the quotes going on to second lines).

Comment: You have this line `boughtw * woodprice - money` where the calculation does update any variable. @BruceWayne it's a recursive function ;-) but I'm not sure it's complete at it will not do for another loop if the user sells or intends to buy and refuses

Comment: I get an error when I run this code. You must either fix your code or add the details of the error.

Comment: There's no specific error it's just not updating the variables and @BruceWayne i did that so when i input it doesn't input right next to the text.

Comment: But **I** get an error. You should fix it so that I don't.

Comment: Well what is the error?

Comment: Error: You assign to `buywcost` in `buysale` (`buywcost = float(amntw) * woodprice`) which makes it a _local_ variable. Therefore it isn't available in all cases and you run into problems here: `if buywyn == ("Yes") and money >= buywcost:`. -> `UnboundLocalError: local variable ' buywcost' referenced before assignment`

Comment: You may have to use repl.it i dont get that error.

Comment: I've run it under repl.it as well as under PyCharm locally. Both time the same error (I chose `Buy` and then `Food`). Also: I don't have to run it, what you are doing goes against the Python syntax rules.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure your issue is in the following bit:

```
    boughtw = amntw
    boughtw = woodinv
    boughtw * woodprice - money
    woodsalea = boughtw
```

so to follow through what each of those does:
At the beginning: boughtw = 0, amntw's value depends on user input, woodinv = 0, woodprice = 2, money = 2, woodsalea = 1

The first line assigns the value of amntw (user input) to boughtw (0). boughtw now has the value the user input.
The second like assigns the value of woodinv (0) to boughtw (user input). boughtw now has a value of 0 again.
The 3rd line calculates a value of -2, but doesn't assign it to anything.
the 4th line assigns the value of boughtw (0) to woodsalea (1). woodsalea now has a value of 0.

I'm pretty sure that what you meant to do was more like:

```
boughtw = float(amntw)
woodinv = woodinv + boughtw
money = money - boughtw * woodprice
woodsalea = boughtw //not entirely sure about this line. I'm not sure what you mean to track with woodsalea
```

There are a lot of other issues with your code. It will crash if people don't enter exactly what you expect or try to follow a path you haven't implemented yet (like buying anything other than Wood), but the above should explain at least why nothing seems to change from one run to the next.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that lines like `woodinv = woodinv + boughtw` where a variable is being modified by another value can be more tersely rewritten as `woodinv += boughtw`.

Comment: Worth noting, yes. But I'm guessing that the OP is very new to programming in general and Python in particular, so I was trying not to cause confusion by adding syntax they might not have seen yet.